# how many pages php is running right now

Tags: php

i open 100 page of p.php by fsocket (asynchroun) and want to know how many of that is open right now and not finished yet !(or if run>0 return 1 else return 0)

1. how can know how many of p.php is running right now(i open p.php by fsocket)?
2. its possible ?:D

Comment: Could you be more specific? Do you want to know have many browsers are open with one of your pages showing?

Comment: Probably wants to know how many socket connections are open/not finished.

Answer (score 3):

First, fsockopen is synchronous in nature so it only sends a single request at time. You should be able to tell that all of the connections are finished when the last one finishes.

If you're looking for an asynchronous alternative, I'd highly recommend using [curl_multi](http://www.php.net/curl_multi_init).